# Importing SVN repository into an existing Git repository as "old" history

Tags: git, svn, import

6 months ago I moved to another company and they allowed me to take just the checkout of an existing Subversion project
Since then I used Git to save my history.

Few days ago the old company allowed me to access the entire Subversion repository so I can take the full history of the project.

The problem is that on top of the last SVN commit (6 months old, no one committed after my departure) I have 6 months of Git commits.

I have already imported everything with `git-svn`, but is there a way to append to this import my last 6 months?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know that much about git-svn but can't you just rebase your 6 months worth of commits onto the last SVN commit? Since nothing changed, there should be no problems/conflicts at all.

Comment: or using `git cherry-pick <last-of-old-repo>..<latest-of-new-repo>`. Anyway, this is an interesting use case but possibly quite unique.